# Can I customize Login button of Twitter kit in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, twitter, acaccountstore

I have downloaded a Twitter kit framework and added code to login with Twitter. But, I don't want Login button look like that. I want a custom button for Login. Can I do that ? I only want to use this framework as this also leverages with iOS system account.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As per the [document](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login) :

Add the code in your button press :

### Objective-C

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
            (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
  if (session) {
      NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}];
```

### Swift

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion {
                (session, error) -> Void in
    if (session != nil) {
        println("signed in as \(session.userName)");
    } else {
        println("error: \(error.localizedDescription)");
    }
}
```

Comment: I also added answer to my question asynchronous, with your answer. Still you deserve up-vote and acceptance.

Comment: @Pratik `[[Twitter sharedInstance] logOut];`

Comment: Already tried, but next time, when I press login button, it does not ask for credentials !!! Directly I get session.

Comment: oh! May be you have to ask question to twitter community iOS. @Pratik

Comment: can any one give me steps for twitter login . i had try so many times but i cant done please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes,you can do customize your Twitter login button.**

*Just add your UIButton in your storyboard's desired View controller. Select it and open the identity inspector, now in the Class textfield, enter "TWTRLogInButton" after that create a property.*

You will create something like this:-

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet TWTRLogInButton *customTwitterButton;
```

After that you can use it or implement it in your `viewDidLoad` method like this:-

```
self.customTwitterButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    // do operations as per your wish
}];
```

Comment: That is not happening in my case.Anyways good to see you found a way by yourself.

Comment: This shouldn't work because `+buttonWithLogInCompletion:` create a new instance of the button, so you override the IBOutlet `self.customTwitterButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has provided a separate method for Sign In in the documentation. Create your custom button in xib or storyboard, give it a selector and add a method for twitter login. Here is an example:

```
- (IBAction)btnTwitterLogin_pressed:(id)sender
{
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
         if (session) {
             NSLog(@"%@", [session userID]);
             NSLog(@"%@", [session userName]);
             NSLog(@"%@", [session authToken]);
             NSLog(@"%@", [session authTokenSecret]);
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }
     }];
}
```

Hope it helps others too.

Comment: How do i login with twitter from web not using the app.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

Default Twitter sign in button code

```
let twitterLoginButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
    if (session != nil) {
       print("signed in as \(session!.userName)");
    } else {
       print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
    }
})

twitterLoginButton.frame  = CGRect(x: 60, y: 100, width: 200, height: 40)
self.view.addSubview(twitterLoginButton)
```

[image]

Normal login button action code

```
@IBAction func onClickTwitterSignin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().logIn { (session, error) in

        if (session != nil) {

            let name = session?.userName ?? ""
            print(name)
            print(session?.userID  ?? "")
            print(session?.authToken  ?? "")
            print(session?.authTokenSecret  ?? "")

            self.loadFollowers(session: session?.userID ?? "")

            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
            client.requestEmail { email, error in
                if (email != nil) {
                    let recivedEmailID = email ?? ""
                    print(recivedEmailID)
                } else {
                    print("error--: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
                }
            }

            let twitterClient = TWTRAPIClient(userID: session?.userID)
            twitterClient.loadUser(withID: session?.userID ?? "") {(user, error) in
                print(user?.profileImageURL ?? "")
                print(user?.profileImageLargeURL ?? "")
                print(user?.screenName ?? "")
            }

            let storyboard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as! SecondViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storyboard, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))");
        }
    }

}
```